# Serialization of Queue type not working

Tags: c#

Consider this piece of code:

```
private Queue Date=new Queue();
//other declarations
public DateTime _Date { 
 get { return (DateTime)Date.Peek();} 
 set { Date.Enqueue(value); } 
 }
 //other properties and stuff....
 public void UpdatePosition(...) 
 {
   //other code

    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream Datestream = new MemoryStream();
    formatter.Serialize(Datestream, Date);
    byte[] Datebin = new byte[2048];
    Datestream.Read(Datebin,0,2048);
    //Debug-Bug
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(this._Date));
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(Datebin, 0, 3));

    //other code
 }
```

The output of the first WriteLine is perfect. I.e to check if really the Queue is initialised or not. It is. The right variables are stored etc. (I inserted a value in that Queue, that part of the code is not shown.)

But the second WriteLine is not giving the right expected answer: It serializes the entire Queue to 00-00-00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

`formatter.Serialize(Datestream, Date)`

to serialize the data, you should use something like

`Date = (Queue)formatter.Deserialize(Datestream)`

to deserialize it. Your current code is using two different and incompatible ways to represent the data in binary format.

As to why you store your `DateTime` instance in a `Queue` named `Date` and name a property `_Date`, that is another question...

Comment: Thanks Peter, Yes I think I will go with this. I was successful in implementing the same in this way: 
`Pos.Date = DeSerFormatter.Deserialize(DateDeserial) as Queue<DateTime>;`

I can understand IL must be the same for both. 
Secondly,I changed the `Queue` type to `Queue<DateTime>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewind the [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) to the start before reading from it:

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Alternatively, if you just want the contents as byte array, use [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=VS.100).aspx) instead of [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.read(v=VS.100).aspx):

```
byte[] buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Do you mean to say, I need to insert this line before populating the Datebin array (with the Read() ? )

Comment: Yes. You need to change the declaration of `Datestream` to `MemoryStream` first to access the property though.

Comment: DTB, do you mean to say DateStream.Position and DateStream.ToArray() ?

Comment: Well, surprise,surprise. I did what you said. Changed DateStream type to MemoryStream and inserting DateStream.Position=0; I am indeed getting a different output this time. 
Instead of the original 00-00-00 I am getting now, 00-01-00.

It doesnt look quite good to me, the inserted date was 17th April 2010 and it serialized into 00-01-00 ? :-o ?

Comment: DTB, I can understand yours also helped. In an ideal world, I would mark both of these answers as possible solutions. But StackOveflow doesnt allow it.